# include inside ng repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to ng-include inside a ng-repeat. But nothing happens. If I include it statically with the whole link it works. Also tried ng-src but also not working.

index.html

```
<div ng-controller="sliderCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="slide in slides">
        <div ng-include src="'/partials/slider/{{slide.image}}.html'"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

sliderCtrl.js

```
MyApp.controller('sliderCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.slides = [
    {image: '01', description: 'Image 00'},
    {image: '02', description: 'Image 01'},
    {image: '03', description: 'Image 02'}
    ];
});
```

console

```
Error: [$interpolate:noconcat] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$interpolate/noconcat?p0='%2Fpartials%2Fslider%2F%7B%7Bslide.image%7D%7D.html'
    at Error (native)
    at http://192.168.33.77/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:6:417
    at g (http://192.168.33.77/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:88:436)
    at Oa (http://192.168.33.77/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:68:208)
    at X (http://192.168.33.77/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:53:397)
    at S (http://192.168.33.77/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:51:428)
    at S (http://192.168.33.77/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:52:95)
    at D (http://192.168.33.77/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:49:467)
    at fa (http://192.168.33.77/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:61:43)
    at S (http://192.168.33.77/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:51:465) <div ng-view="" class="page ng-scope">
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does the console say? Any errors?

Comment: Yes totally forgot to add console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
<div ng-include src="'/partials/slider/{{slide.image}}.html'"></div>
```

Use this:

```
<div ng-include src="'/partials/slider/' + slide.image + '.html'"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using data-ng-include data-src:

```
<div ng-controller="sliderCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="slide in slides">
        <div data-ng-include data-src="'/partials/slider/{{slide.image}}.html'"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Should not be the problem, but you never know.

Comment: Thanks but just tried it still not working. I added the error message in my post that I had.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to escape the inner quotes:

```
<div ng-controller="sliderCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="slide in slides">
        <div ng-include src="\'/partials/slider/{{slide.image}}.html\'"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks tried escaping the inner quotes but still had the same error. Error: [$interpolate:noconcat]